# Is there a way for get-help for as specific cmdlet to NOT show certain parameters?

Tags: powershell

I have this cmdlet that did one thing, but as time progressed, because of the name had to do something different now. But not to break anyone, it does both things now.  But I have a new cmdlet that does what it used to do. So, when someone calls get-help on the original cmdlet I do not want to show any parameters it still supports only so existing scripts do not break.

Thoughts?